# MR16 Led bulbs not working in 2000ish sockets

Tags: led, light-bulb

We moved into new house which was built in the very late 90s

One of the first things I did was try to change all of the bulbs from Alls electric bulbs to LED bulbs

Almost all the sockets are MR16

In some sockets the LED bulbs just wouldn’t work at all. Though often the dimmable variety would work even if not on a dimmer while the non dimmable wouldn’t work.

In our bedroom / bathroom neither variety will work at all. Only the old fashioned power hogging ones

We’ve seen an electrician who says it’s something to do with the transformers but I can’t find anything about this anywhere online.

Does anybody know anything about this? / what to do about it. And maybe if it’s possible to buy A type of LED bulb to solve it.

On the dimmer circuits where they do work we get a lot of flashing especially towards the lower side of travel for the dimmer. But often when the dimmer is set ok bulbs will just start flashing reliquiring us to jiggle them a bit to at least temporarily stop the flashing

Dan

Comment: Have you opened up one of the bad dimmer switches? If they’re original to the house construction, they probably aren’t led compatible. The other thing is that bi pin mr16 bases can get loose over time — sometimes only showing up when dimming. These can be replaced or sometimes carefully fiddled with to make good contact.

Comment: Sounds like the bulbs are not a fit. What is the provenance of them?  "bought em off amazon/ebay" might be part of it.

Comment: your last line is the key clue. try bending the prongs together or apart to ensure a tight fit in the socket, or replace the socket of you're feeling ambitious.